# Immigration to Switzerland with both sets of parents

Tags: immigration, family, switzerland, unemployment-benefits

My husband and I would like to relocate to Switzerland from South Africa but we want to find out if it is possible to take both parents along (they will not be working). Unfortunately, our parents are very reliant on us and we won't be able to start the moving process if we cannot take them along... any advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Should we assume that you are both citizens of South Africa and of no other country?

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that this is possible. Family reunification rules provide that third country nationals may only bring the following family members to Switzerland:

- your spouse or registered partner;
- your unmarried children under the age of 18.

Source: https://www.ch.ch/en/foreign-nationals-in-switzerland/living-in-switzerland/family-reunification/